# Stripe instant verification for ACH with DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using Stripe to collect payments on DocuSign envelope. For ACH payments DocuSign is using Stripe's micro deposit option to verify Bank. I want to use instant verification option here by integrating Plaid with Stripe or Using Stripe ACH Direct Debit but can't find any clue on how to get it working with DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

Could please directly open a Docusign support case regarding this payment question.
It will be taken in charge by our eSignature support team
Please follow this guide to open a support case:
https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-Do-I-Open-a-Case-in-the-DocuSign-Support-Center?language=en_US&rsc_301

Comment: I have already opened a ticket with DocuSign & they referred me this article
https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&langSet=1&bundleId=juu1573854950452&topicId=wcl1659141859619.html&_LANG=enus

I have made the changes as suggested but it doesn't work. And after reviewing logs on Stripe for payment request from DocuSign I can see that DocuSign is not sending any parameters for automatic validation/ instant verification.

Comment: I have enabled Financial Connections on Stripe & can do instant verification when using Stripe Checkout but instant verification not working when paying through DocuSign.